# Is it possible to conceal a OS X app from DTrace?

Tags: macos, dtrace

I am developing an OS X application that I would like to conceal from inspection by DTrace. I'm aware of the `P_LNOATTACH` flag, but everything I've read tells me that there are ways around it. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's possible.  Try running DTrace against iTunes; it doesn't work.

You have to call the ptrace function with PT_DENY_ATTACH.

http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man2/ptrace.2.html

However, there are ways around it with various kext's.  Google around and you'll find some of them.

for 10.6 & 10.7:  https://github.com/dwalters/pt_deny_attach

Hmm, Looks like it's broken with 10.8 due to ASLR:  [Detecting, and Shirking Off, the Debugger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14515042/detecting-and-shirking-off-the-debugger)

Comment: You could improve the answer by pointing to a kext that works with 10.7.x

Answer (score 4):

As noted, you can use ptrace(2) with PT_DENY_ATTACH, but DTrace or a debugger can intercept those calls and disable them. Further, you want your users using DTrace on your program. If there's a problem, let them help you diagnose it. The only truly proprietary software executes on controlled environments like appliances and the cloud -- once you hand a user your bits, the only thing in the way of understanding what you're doing is time.